# Season 5 "The Thrill" Conquest - Definition of "Reach"

Tags: diablo-iii

In Season 5 of Diablo 3, the conquest "*The Thrill*" is defined as: "***Reach*** GR45 without any set item equipped". My question is what is considered as "Reach"?

To elaborate: Do I need to clear GR45 in the time limit required for upgrading gems (15 minutes), or do I just need to complete the level (ie. defeat the Rift Guardian) in ANY time length?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to complete the Rift (Kill the RG) in less than 15 minutes